# Troubles with argv :uninitialized constant ARVG (NameError)

Tags: ruby, argv

I am working through a tutorial in which I have built a text analyzer. At this point it is built and working as expected and I am now supposed to include a summarizer which will find the most relevant sentences to summarize the text. That is also built and working as expected. It is in a separate file, as specified. My problem is getting ARVG to read the files. I also have some confusion as to how the summarize.rb file is included. This the first time doing this so please correct me where my logic and/or code is wrong.

I have 3 files:

1) text.txt -> which holds the original text

2) summarize.rb -> holds the program to analyze the text in text.txt

3) ARGV.rb -> to run the text through summarize??

The instructions state I should be writing, in the command line

```
ruby analyzer.rb text.txt
```

to which I receive an error:

```
analyzer.rb:5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ARVG (NameError)
```

the instructions say nothing about needing to initialize anything concerning running the arvg file.

here is what is in my analyzer.rb file

```
File.open("text.txt") 

lines = File.readlines(ARVG[0]) 
line_count = lines.size #this counts the lines in the new array
text = lines.join 
total_characters = text.length
total_characters_nonspace = text.gsub(/\s/, '').length
word_count = text.split.length
total_sentences = text.split(/\.|\?|!/).length
paragraphs = text.split(/\n\n/).count 
words_per_sentence = word_count / total_sentences
sentences_per_paragraph = total_sentences / paragraphs

stop_words = %w(the by a on the for of are with just but and to the my I has some in)


#puts text
puts
puts "stats:"
puts "#{line_count} lines"
puts "#{total_characters} total characters"
puts "#{total_characters_nonspace} total characters not including spaces"
puts "#{word_count} is the word count"
puts "#{total_sentences} is the number of sentences"
puts "#{paragraphs} total paragraphs"
puts
puts "Averages:"
puts "#{words_per_sentence} average words per sentence"
puts "#{sentences_per_paragraph} average sentences per paragraph"
puts
```

Here is what is in my summerize.rb file - it may be worth noting that in the lesson, the text to be summarized has hardcoded in the file and attached to a variable. Also none of this was wrapped as a method. I made it a method that takes a argument (whatever text) because it made more sense to make it reusable with any text rather what was hard-coded in the file. The instructions never specified to do that. It just left the hardcoded text in. Could the changes be a problem?

```
def summarizer (str)
  sentences = str.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip.split(/\.|\?|!/) 
  sentences_sorted = sentences.sort_by{|sentence| sentence.length} 
  one_third = sentences_sorted.length / 3 
  ideal_sentences = sentences_sorted.slice(one_third, one_third + 1) 
  ideal_sentences = ideal_sentences.select{|sentence| sentence =~ /is|are/} 
  puts ideal_sentences.join('. ')
end
```

Here is what summarize.rb looked like before I changed it from what the lesson specified.

```
text = %q{Ruby is a great programming language. It is object oriented and has many groovey features. Some people don't like it but that's not our problem! It's easy to learn.It's great. To learn more about Ruby visit the official Ruby website today}

  sentences = text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip.split(/\.|\?|!/) #getting rid of white space and splitting @ end of sentence
  sentences_sorted = sentences.sort_by{|sentence| sentence.length} #sorts sentences by length
  one_third = sentences_sorted.length / 3 #calculates what a third of sentences are since we don't want too many.
  ideal_sentences = sentences_sorted.slice(one_third, one_third + 1) #slices out the first and last third
  ideal_sentences = ideal_sentences.select{|sentence| sentence =~ /is|are/} #<= defines words we are looking for
  puts ideal_sentences.join('. ')
```

And here is what is in my ARGV.rb file

```
puts ARGV.join('-')
```

as instructed.

My questions are, why isn't this working...and how is the text.txt file being run through summarize.rb (which is what I think is supposed to be happening)when summarize.rb is never called by ARGV.rb nor text.txt? And this is exactly how the instructions indicated I set this up (I've read them at least five times in case I missed something...)

Comment: shouldn't this be "`ARGV`" and not "`AGRV`"? i.e. if you switch "`ARVG[0]`" to "`ARGV[0]`", will all be okay?

Comment: Good eyes!!! I totally missed that!! Thanks!  It is running now, but it is not running the script from the summarize file...how do I get that incorporated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
analyzer.rb:5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant ARVG (NameError)
```

This message is telling you that there is a problem on line 5 of your program.

Which I'm assuming is this line:

```
lines = File.readlines(ARVG[0])
```

It's telling you that you haven't initialised a constant called `ARVG`... which is correct - you are using a constant called `ARVG` ... but I'm assuming what you *meant* to use was the constant `ARGV` (note spelling mistake)?

Comment: Thank you @Taryn East! The guy just before you caught that and you are both correct, I had a typo. But I am still confused as to how the summarize.rb file comes into play when it seems nothing is calling it?

Comment: I answered your original question (and there wasn't a comment there when I did, but it probably took me longer to write mine and the comment came through meanwhile). :) Now: I'm not at all sure where you even have a reference to summarise. your usage stats you call analyzer.rb and that's where the error is... and the error talks about ARVG which is a line in analyzer,rb ... so where/why are you bringing in summarise?

Comment: well that's what I am confused about. The tutorial had us create the summarize.rb, and use it to summarize some text that was hardcoded into the summarize.rb file(you can see in my question the original summarize file)...then jumped right into running the argv file from the prompt line. I can only assume it (summarize.rb) is supposed to be used in conjunction with the argv and analyzer files...but it never stated how to incorporate it. I read the section a bunch of times but don't see how it's included. So how WOULD I include it?

Comment: I'd recommend you start by creating a separate question to this one ;) So the two don't get mixed up.

Comment: But from a quick overview reading, I'm guesing it's possible that your ARGV.rb and summarize.rb are actually meant to be the same file (but the original problem was edited and the name changed in one place but not both) ? Note: ARGV is a *really* strange name to call a ruby file. Sso it's possible this was the first name... but it was changed to summarize.rb later

Comment: yes I edited it because I kept writing arvg instead of argv, I actually did it once in my file which is what you guys pointed out and that's why the code didn't run initially. I left the original error in the question, since thats what the initial problem was. I am guessing that yes, perhaps the summarize is not meant to be run with the argv, but separately somehow - though I don't think it was supposed to be part of the analyzer.rb (I agree it would make sense to have it there) as the tutorial was pretty specific about setting it up in a separate file. It just didn't say how to link it.

Comment: No i mean maybe the original tutorial was edited... hough seriously - at this point... create a new stack overflow question for this different problem sow e can figure it out. Also - it'd help if you can provide a link to the original tutorial wording  so we can see what was original written and figure out what was meant.

Comment: I wish I could but It's not online,it's from Peter Cooper's 'Beginning Ruby: From Novice to Professional' book (kindle). So I guess I will just have to figure it out or hope later example will help clarify this one. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can summarise the step-by-step and give us exact details on the bits that mention files. (but do it in a new question, as these comments are off-topic now) ;)